# Android Layout with images and text

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I am trying to make a layout with an image on the left side, then a text, and two images on the right side. I show you how it likes now:

[image: layout]

I want to put the two right icons on the right side, next to the limit of the screen. Then, if you see, when the text has more than one line, the two icons disappear and when the text is too long the icons are very small. I want a static space for every one of the icons.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:padding="6dip">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:contentDescription="@string/cdLogo" />


 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lista2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingRight="20dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dip">

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tituloevento"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/distritoevento"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textSize="12sp"/>

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/coorp0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />


 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/coorp1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/esgratis"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/caracteristicas"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lista2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">  


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iconoMapa"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/cdTieneCoor"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"/>  


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iconoGratis"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/cdGratisPago"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

   </LinearLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I really suggest you use a custom layout instead of such a relatively complex RelativeLayout to improve your performance. Especially if you're using it as a ListView item.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use a `LinearLayout` as the top container, and distribute the space of the child elements with `weight` attributes. When using weight, you must set `layout_width` to `0dp` for horizontal layouts or `layout_heigth` to `0dp` for vertical layouts.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```